# Why Apache Tika detect mimetype of a jar file as application/zip instead of application/java-archive?

Tags: java, jar, mime-types, apache-tika

I am trying to detect mime-type for a jar file code is working fine, but the issue is `Apache Tika` returns `application/zip` instead of `application/java-archive` for a java `Jar` file

I Uploaded Jar file from html

```
for (FileItem item : fileItems)
        {  
            String mimeType;
            try { 
                mimeType = tika.detect(item.getInputStream());
                System.out.println(mimeType); // returns application/zip
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

So my question is how to get application/java-archive mime-type for a jar file.

Is there any way to configure Apache Tika or I am doing something wrong

Comment: Can you try passing in the filename as well? eg [detect with the File object instead](https://tika.apache.org/1.24/api/org/apache/tika/Tika.html#detect-java.io.File-)?

Comment: @Gagravarr what it will do ?

Comment: Probably figure out the specific subtype of jar!

Comment: I dont have file, I just have inputstream

Comment: Actually I am trying to implement a Authenticated file uploader, Like I don't want to upload jar file, but someone can change the extention from `jar` to `txt` and then upload. So i want to restrict that kind of upload

Comment: Jar is a subtype of zip. Without the file extension, all you can do is say "is this a zip-based format" or not

Comment: Alternately, if you make sure you have the Tika Parser jar on your classpath, and you pass a `TikaInputStream` to detect, Tika will be able to detect the jar subtype

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal viable example. I am naive 

Comment: Just wrap it in [TikaInputStream.get(InputStream)](https://tika.apache.org/1.24/api/org/apache/tika/io/TikaInputStream.html#get-java.io.InputStream-) before you pass it to Tika

Comment: Okay, let me try.

Comment: I tried but still no success, Still getting `application/zip` PS: the input stream that I have is from Apache Common FileUploader, this is a input stream fetching from FileItem

Comment: Make sure you have the Tika Parsers jar on your classpath along with the dependencies of it - the Tika Core jar isn't enough for detecting inside container formats like zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Gagravarr I able to fix this issue

So what my code is look like

```
public static TikaConfig getTikaConfig() {
        TikaConfig tikaConfig = null;
        try {
            return new TikaConfig();
        } catch (TikaException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tikaConfig;
    }
public static final TikaConfig tikaConfig = getTikaConfig();
MediaType mediaType = tikaConfig.getDetector()
                                        .detect(TikaInputStream
                                                    .get(item.getInputStream()), new Metadata());
                MimeType mimeType = tikaConfig.getMimeRepository().forName(mediaType.toString());
                String extension =  mimeType.getExtension().split("\\.")[1];
System.out.println("File extention is :"+extension);
```

Most important gralde config

```
compile group: 'org.apache.tika', name: 'tika-core', version: '1.24.1'
runtime group: 'org.apache.tika', name: 'tika-parsers' version: '1.24.1'
```

Comment: I am still getting .zip for jar file for mimeType.getExtension(). is this working for you ?